# phpexcel with Bloomberg

Tags: php, phpexcel, bloomberg

I am trying to create an Excel workbook using PHPExcel...

Everything works fine with most of the columns I'm creating.

However, the last column contains a formula (BDH) which belongs to Bloomberg's Excel Addin. This workbook will be used, of course, on a Bloomberg Terminal.

PHPExcel returns an error when I try to enter the Bloomberg formula on this column. I have successfully entered regular formulas in the column, so I assume the problem is that PHPExcel doesn't know the Bloomberg formula I am entering...

Any thoughts?

```
$Formula="=BDH(\"$My_Asset\" , \"px_last\" , \"$My_Date\" , \"$My_Date\" , \"$My_Overrides\" )";
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue("G1",$Formula);
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You're correct in your assumption: PHPExcel will only work with functions that are "native" to Excel itself, not with functions that are added to Excel through external packs, nor with User-Defined functions. Nor is there any method of adding these non-native functions.

Comment: Ok, Thank you sir!